# Collaborative development workflow using Poetry

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm trying to understand what's "Poetic" way of collaborating in a team. Assume the team is maintaining two packages `base_foo` and `foo`. Every team member has a local copy of the packages (very likely in different location on the local storage). Next, it is common that while developing `foo` there's a need to make changes in `base_foo`. What's the best `Poetry` way around this?

Without having Poetry, I would have considered something like `pip install -e /local/path/to/base_foo`, but this is probably too naive of an approach. My second idea is to use the `my-package = {path = "/local/path/to/base_foo", develop = true}` approach. However, two questions pop up:

1. How to separate the local development environment and the "production" one (which would probably need to point to a private registry/pypi/etc.)?
2. <s>What's the canonical way to cater for different local paths that different developers have on their local machines?</s> See NB.

N.B. 2022-10-20: As for the 2nd part, I guess this is where team conventions can be very helpful. For example, agree that all projects are checked out in one directory. In this case it'll be possible to specify relative path like `my-package = {path = "../base_foo", develop = true}`.

Comment: I do not know if there is a better way in Poetry now, but it used to be that a recommendation was to duplicate the dependency in the production and in the development blocks. Where the dev dependency has the `develop = true` with a local path.

Comment: And how can I control which one is used?

Comment: When the project is installed with Poetry, the dev dependency is used (the dependency is installed as editable from the local path), but the production dependency is written in the sdist and wheel metadata. At least this should be the expected behavior. It has some drawbacks, but should be helpful enough for some basic use cases.